How to dynamically create threads depending upon the CPU usage to execute the script faster
I am making a program in python which take in a large list and use each item of the list to perform a task.
One way to make this efficient is to split the list in multiple parts and then use multi threading on those sub-lists to reduce the time of execution.
My question is how we can dynamically create threads (sub processes) depending upon how much CPU is being used (other apps might also be running in the background). For example if there are no background processes running, I want my script to dynamically create maximum available sub processes (threads) and reduce the execution time to a great extent, and if there are other task running in the background, it should create fewer number of sub processes.
We can use multi threading in python by manually creating threads, but I want it to happen dynamically, which should also take in account how much cpu does other applications are using and make more threads accordingly.
Update
I want this function to run concurrently in multiple threads:
def func(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(URL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        opDiv = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'offer_price'})
        offerPriceText = opDiv.find('span', attrs = {'class':'m-w'}).text
        minPrice.append(float(offerPriceText[1:].replace(',', '')))   
    except:
        minPrice.append(None)


What are these tasks you want to perform? You will be disappointed with threads if they are CPU bound. If they are not (like network bound) then it won't matter so much what other apps are running in the background.

I have a large list of links, I want to extract the data from each link.

Then threads are not what you are looking for. Multiple processes might help.

You need to give example code which works for just one link for us to imagine what a concurrent program would need to be.

Updated my question with the example code @quamrana

@KlausD. could you please tell me how I can track the cpu capacity to handle multiple processes and create multi process for my script dynamically

I would say that with such little CPU involvement that you can use the thread based pool from this answer
